# Why does this code not print anything?

Tags: c#, debugging

I am trying to create a working program where you have to input town, product and quantity and output the total price.

For example Town1>Milk>2 should result in `2`. But for some reason, there is no output. Can somebody please help me and show me the mistake?

Here is the code:

```
Console.Write("Enter product: ");
var product = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
Console.Write("Enter town: ");
var town = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
Console.Write("Enter quantity: ");
var quantity = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

if (town == "Town1")
{
    if (product == "Milk")
        Console.WriteLine(1.50 * quantity);
    if (product == "Water")
        Console.WriteLine(0.80 * quantity);
    if (product == "Whiskey")
        Console.WriteLine(4.20 * quantity);
    if (product == "Peanuts")
        Console.WriteLine(0.90 * quantity);
    if (product == "Chocolate")
        Console.WriteLine(2.60 * quantity);   
}
if (town == "Town2")
{
    if (product == "Milk")
        Console.WriteLine(1.40 * quantity);
    if (product == "Water")
        Console.WriteLine(0.70 * quantity);
    if (product == "Whiskey")
        Console.WriteLine(3.90 * quantity);
    if (product == "Peanuts")
        Console.WriteLine(0.70 * quantity);
    if (product == "Chocolate")
        Console.WriteLine(1.50 * quantity);
}
if (town == "Town3")
{
    if (product == "Milk")
        Console.WriteLine(1.90 * quantity);
    if (product == "Water")
         Console.WriteLine(1.50 * quantity);
    if (product == "Whiskey")
         Console.WriteLine(5.10 * quantity);
    if (product == "Peanuts")
         Console.WriteLine(1.35 * quantity);
    if (product == "Chocolate")
         Console.WriteLine(3.10 * quantity);
}
}}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting `town = value.ToLower()` and `product = value.ToLower()`, this makes all characters lowercase, change these lines:

```
var town = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
var product = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

To this:

```
var town = Console.ReadLine();
var product = Console.ReadLine();
```

OR change your if statement conditions to use lowercase values as comparisons

```
if (town == "town1")
{
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately it is still not working :(

Comment: That is because your other values are being set ToLower() as well and you are trying to compare that to values with UpperCase characters. Do the same for product as well as town.

Answer (score 1):

For bonus points, consider using a `Dictionary<,>`, which will also allow you to specify that a case-insensitive comparison should be performed.

```
var townProductPrices = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) {
    ["Town1"] = new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) {
        ["Milk"] = 1.50d,
        ["Water"] = 0.80d,
        ["Whiskey"] = 4.20d,
        ["Peanuts"] = 0.90d,
        ["Chocolate"] = 2.60d,
    },
    ["Town2"] = new Dictionary<string, double>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) {
        ["Milk"] = 1.40d,
        ["Water"] = 0.70d,
        ["Whiskey"] = 3.90d,
        ["Peanuts"] = 0.70d,
        ["Chocolate"] = 1.50d,
    },
    //...
};


Console.Write("Enter product: ");
var product = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
Console.Write("Enter town: ");
var town = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
Console.Write("Enter quantity: ");
var quantity = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Trim());

var productPrices = townProductPrices[town];
var price = productPrices[product];
var total = price * quantity;
Console.WriteLine(total.ToString("c"));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! What does Dictionary<,>, ToString and StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase mean?

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is a `Dictionary` class that uses a Generic Typing. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `ToString("c")` converts the double/decimal value to a string using currency formatting. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b22a4x2(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` specifies that the Dictionary should use the current user/system Culture and _ignore_ casing when retrieving values. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Generic types are probably a little advanced for a new programmer but this solution is good. I didn't know about that dictionary overload, thank you! Oh, you probably can remove the tolowers on the user input and optionally replace them with trims?

Comment: Great suggestion to add the `Trim()` methods, I had forgotten to remove the `ToLower()` methods as well which was why I had suggested the case-comparison overload. Example has been updated.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need these many matches. If at all this matters, Try this:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter product: ");
        var product = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        Console.Write("Enter town: ");
        var town = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        Console.Write("Enter quantity: ");
        var quantity = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var mapperData = new List<Mapper>()
                         {
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town1", ProductInfo = "Milk", Quantity = 1.50 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town1", ProductInfo = "Water", Quantity = 0.80 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town1", ProductInfo = "Whiskey", Quantity = 4.20 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town1", ProductInfo = "Peanuts", Quantity = 0.90 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town1", ProductInfo = "Chocolate", Quantity = 2.60 },

                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town2", ProductInfo = "Milk", Quantity = 1.40 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town2", ProductInfo = "Water", Quantity = 0.70 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town2", ProductInfo = "Whiskey", Quantity = 3.90 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town2", ProductInfo = "Peanuts", Quantity = 0.70 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town2", ProductInfo = "Chocolate", Quantity = 1.50 },

                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town3", ProductInfo = "Milk", Quantity = 1.90 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town3", ProductInfo = "Water", Quantity = 1.50 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town3", ProductInfo = "Whiskey", Quantity = 5.10 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town3", ProductInfo = "Peanuts", Quantity = 1.35 },
                             new Mapper { TownName = "Town3", ProductInfo = "Chocolate", Quantity = 3.10 },
                         };

        var matchingQuantity = mapperData.FirstOrDefault(i => i.TownName.ToString().ToLower() == town.ToLower().Trim()
                                                  && i.ProductInfo.ToString().ToLower() == product.ToLower().Trim()).Quantity;
        Console.WriteLine(matchingQuantity * quantity);
    }
}

public class Mapper
{
    public string TownName { get; set; }
    public string ProductInfo { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, you can even create enums for town and product and use them.

Comment: Thank you! Its working! But what does Mapper, { get; set; } and Trim mean?

Comment: Mapper is a class that has three values. For getter and setter read online about it how to use them in c#. Trim is used on strings in c# to remove empty spaces

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question and isn't the best implementation to suggest either